# terminal resize confuses emacs

Tags: emacs

When I unplug my laptop from my monitor emacs seems to think the monitor is still the terminal is still the same size, which makes splitting windows not work (e.g. the vertical bar will be on the far right side of the window).

Is there a way to get emacs to re-examine the terminal settings? (this is also emacs running under screen)

Also: quitting emacs and starting it again causes it to work properly, so the problem appears to be contained in emacs

(on Linux connecting from Mac OS X terminal)

Comment: linux, via Max OS X's terminal

Answer (score 0):

I have similar behavior on my macbook. after unplugging the monitor, resize the terminal (+) and in emacs `C-x 1` to remove the split and get the split back by `C-x 3` (since you had a vertical split).